# Configuring HSQL Server for Hibernate tests

Tags: java, database, hibernate, unit-testing, hsqldb

I'm just starting with Hibernate and getting my head around things.

Currently I'm trying to setup a testing environment where I can use a HSQL in-memory instance to test my project.

The error I'm running into is:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: invalid schema name: TSG
```

Here are the relevant parts of my project:

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
        com.foo.api.models.tsg.AlgPpcAlgorithmOutputEntity

```
<persistence-unit name="TestingPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.foo.api.models.tsg.AlgPpcAlgorithmOutputEntity
    </class>
    <properties>
        <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:tsg"/>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

As you can see, I have one `peristence-unit` for production (which works fine) and one in-memory HSQL one for testing (which I can't get to work).

An example Hibernate entity:

```
package com.foo.api.models.tsg;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@IdClass(AlgPpcAlgorithmOutputEntityPK.class)
@Table(name = "alg_ppc_algorithm_output", schema = "", catalog = "tsg")
@Entity
public class AlgPpcAlgorithmOutputEntity {
    private int parameterId;

    @Column(name = "parameter_id")
    @Id
    public int getParameterId() {
        return parameterId;
    }

    public void setParameterId(int parameterId) {
        this.parameterId = parameterId;
    }

    private String matchType;

    @Column(name = "matchType")
    @Basic
    public String getMatchType() {
        return matchType;
    }

    // for brevity I have removed the rest of the implementation
    // It was auto-generated by Hibernate and works fine in production.
}
```

Finally, a simple TestCase class:

```
package tests.integration;


import com.foo.api.models.tsg.AlgPpcAlgorithmOutputEntity;
import com.foo.api.util.HibernateUtil;
import org.hsqldb.Server;
import org.hsqldb.persist.HsqlProperties;
import org.hsqldb.server.ServerConfiguration;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import tests.util.HSQLServerUtil;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import com.foo.api.KeywordManager;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class KeywordManagerTestCase {

    private static final Logger LOG =   LoggerFactory.getLogger(KeywordManagerTestCase.class);
    private EntityManagerFactory eMF;
    protected EntityManager eM;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        HsqlProperties props = new HsqlProperties();
        props.setProperty("server.database.0", "mem:tsg");
        props.setProperty("server.dbname.0", "tsg");

        ServerConfiguration.translateDefaultDatabaseProperty(props);

        Server hsqlServer = new Server();
        hsqlServer.setRestartOnShutdown(false);
        hsqlServer.setNoSystemExit(true);
        hsqlServer.setProperties(props);
        hsqlServer.setTrace(true);

        LOG.info("Configured the HSQLDB server...");
        hsqlServer.start();
        LOG.info("HSQLDB server started on port " + hsqlServer.getPort() + "...");

        LOG.info("Loading hibernate...");
        if (eMF == null) {
            eMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestingPersistenceUnit");
        }

        eM = eMF.createEntityManager();
    }

    /**
     * shutdown the server.
     * @throws Exception in case of errors.
     */
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        eM.close();
        HSQLServerUtil.getInstance().stop();
    }

    /**
     * Demo test to see that the number of user records in the database corresponds the flat file inserts.
     */
    @Test
    public void testDemo1() {
        AlgPpcAlgorithmOutputEntity entity = new AlgPpcAlgorithmOutputEntity();
        entity.setParameterId(200);
        entity.setMatchType("aa");
        KeywordManager km;
        eM.persist(entity);

        HashSet<Integer> params = new HashSet<Integer>();
        params.add(200);
        km = new KeywordManager(eM, params, new Date[2]);

        HashSet<AlgPpcAlgorithmOutputEntity> res = km.pullKeywords(params);
        for (AlgPpcAlgorithmOutputEntity s : res) {
            System.out.println(s.getMatchType());
        }

    }


}
```

I'm sure I have set something up in a strange way, but as I say - this is my very first stab.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

- Have the testing configuration (along with all the hibernate class mapping)for the HSQL db present in persistence.xml
- Have the HSQL db start for unit tests and create and in-memory database with my project's schema (as described in persistence.xml under the class elements).
- Create entity objects and add them to the test db at test-time so I can use the db for my integration tests.

I just can't get past this PersistenceException!

**UPDATE**

OK, so I realised that I didn't need to setup an explicit HSQL server in the setup of my test cases, because that's exactly what the `persistence-unit` entry in my `persistence.xml` is for. Also I have attempted to ALTER the CATALOG so that it matches the catalog used by my mapping classes. The setup of my test case now looks like:

```
private EntityManagerFactory eMF;
protected EntityManager eM;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    LOG.info("Loading hibernate...");
    if (eMF == null) {
        eMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestingPersistenceUnit");
    }

    eM = eMF.createEntityManager();

    EntityTransaction eT = null;
    eT = eM.getTransaction();
    eT.begin();
    Query q = eM.createNativeQuery("ALTER CATALOG PUBLIC RENAME TO TSG");
    q.executeUpdate();
    eT.commit();

    // And also it seems I need to create the schema
    eT = eM.getTransaction();
    eT.begin();
    q = eM.createNativeQuery("CREATE SCHEMA TSG AUTHORIZATION DBA");
    q.executeUpdate();
    eT.commit();
}
```

However, I just end up with a new error now, specifically:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ALG_PPC_ALGORITHM_OUTPUT
```

So I'm getting somewhere but it seems the tables are not being created. I wonder if there is an issue with my `persistence.xml`?

Comment: What is your database file name? `tsg`?

Comment: @YogendraSingh I want to use an in-memory database so I don't wish to have a database file. However, on production (a remote mysql server), the *name* of the database is *tsg*. Am I specifying something that means I'm inadvertently trying to use a file-based DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying server name in the URL but trying to use memory database, which is causing the issue.

Try using the DB URL as:

```
           jdbc:hsqldb:mem:tsg
```

i.e.

```
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:tsg"/>
```

Also use `ALTER CATALOG RENAME TO tsg` to change the default catalog name(PUBLIC).

EDIT: To auto create the schema, update below in persistence.xml (hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto in place of hbm2ddl.auto)

```
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
```

Comment: @Edwardr: Update the key name in your persistence.xml as `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` i.e. `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>`.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out about 15 minutes ago! What an annoying typo! Anyway, this makes progress but the situation now is that the tables are being created before the setup() runs, so they are in the wrong schema etc. However, everything works perfect if I use something like Derby so that's what I'll probably do. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know (and I am not a HSQL expert), the `TSG` you specify in the connection url is the database name which is not the same as the catalog.  See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_schemas_schema_objects

> In HyperSQL, there is only one catalog per database. The name of the catalog is PUBLIC. You can rename the catalog with the ALTER CATALOG RENAME TO statement. All schemas belong the this catalog. The catalog name has no relation to the file name of the database.

As I read that, when HSQL creates a database it creates a catalog named `PUBLIC` within that database and a schema named `PUBLIC` within that catalog.  There can only ever be one catalog per HSQL database.  There can be multiple schemas within that single catalog.

The error you are getting comes actually from the attempt to specify `catalog = "tsg"` in your mapping.  That catalog does not exist.  Since the HSQL database can contain only one catalog, you will have to rename that `PUBLIC` catalog to `TSG` (or change up your mapping).

Comment: This is correct. There is no TSG catalog unless you rename the PUBLIC catalog.

Comment: Hi thanks for this answer. I've attempted to make progress and updated my question. Still stuck I'm afraid.

Comment: Why did you rename the schema?  Should not matter.  Your mapping only named a catalog.  What is the "object name" Hibernate puts together for `@Table(name = "alg_ppc_algorithm_output", schema = "", catalog = "tsg")`?  Should be `tsg..alg_ppc_algorithm_output`.  Is that what you see?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the entity mapping for your unit test by dropping in an orm.xml file to your src/test/resources/META-INF (in case of using the maven layout). In this you can override the JPA annotation mappings. For your needs you just need to override the table location, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

  <entity class="com.foo.api.models.tsg.AlgPpcAlgorithmOutputEntity">
    <table name="alg_ppc_algorithm_output"/>
  </entity>

</entity-mappings>
```

This will place your table into the default public catalog of the hsqldb database, so you don't have to alter the hsqldb scheme. It may even work when your unit test uses multiple catalogs containing tables with the same name, as you just have to give different names in the table name attribute.

Comment: Got it working.However there is a strange issue; If I call test through Eclipse, orm.xml is picked up by entitymanager, but if I run calling mvn clean install orm.xml is not used. After looking into debug I noticed issue is due to use of "root url" in org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration. In case of Eclipse root url refers to test-classes dir where Meta-inf/orm.xml is found. In case of mvn clean install root url refers to domain.jar, generated by separate module (project has a domain and repository layer). Since i can not include the test orm.xml in the domain jar, is there a way arround this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an obvious error in the setup. The connection URL must point to the Server:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/tsg"/>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to connect to an *in-memory* database. According to these docs: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html there is no need to specify localhost is there?

Comment: In that case the server you are starting in your test setup() method is not being used.

Comment: OK, I just realised like an idiot that I'm duplicating server configuration. The persistence-unit outlined in my persistence.xml is taking care of the server starting/stopping for me, right? The `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestingPersistenceUnit");` line is enough to get the server up and running, right?

Comment: The ALTER statement should be `ALTER CATALOG PUBLIC RENAME TO TSG`.

Comment: Oops. So I have that sorted and also I'm creating the schema too. Now just to see why the tables are not created.. I thought all this was supposed to be taken care of by Hibernate!

Comment: Why would you think Hibernate would manage renaming catalogs and schema for you?  How is that a "core competency" of an O/RM?!